# Starting TCP server in Haskell

Tags: sockets, haskell, tcpserver

I am trying to create a TCP server in Haskell from the example provided on [haskell.org](https://wiki.haskell.org/Implement_a_chat_server). When I run the code from the terminal with `ghc run Main.hs`, I get:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main.exe ...
```

After which it closes.

**Code**

```
module Main where 
    import Network.Socket
    import Network.Socket.ByteString
    import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

    main::IO()
    main=do
        sock<-socket AF_INET Stream 0
        bind sock (SockAddrInet 8100 iNADDR_ANY)
        listen sock 2
        mainloop sock


    mainloop::Socket->IO()
    mainloop sock=do
        conn<-accept sock
        runConn conn
        mainloop sock


    runConn::(Socket,SockAddr)->IO()
    runConn (sock,_)=do
        Network.Socket.ByteString.send sock (C.pack "hello")
        close sock
```

I first assumed the server might somehow run in the backgroud so I tested it with the `Simple Web Socket Client` - browser extension and nada.

**Tested url**
`ws://localhost:8100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute your binaries after compiling them:
`./Main` on linux or `Main.exe` on windows.

Then you can request your server thanks to `telnet localhost 8100`

`telnet localhost 8100
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
helloConnection closed by foreign host.`

Comment: But still the connection closes after 1 message sent.

Comment: Check at [link](https://catonmat.net/simple-haskell-tcp-server). It will show you a great example of a TCP server.